# Stand alone ResourceDictionary resource not found

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, resourcedictionary

I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries#stand-alone-resource-dictionaries but i get the error.

> XFC0124 Resource "ResourceDictionary1.xaml" not found.

my code is

ResourceDictionary1.xaml (code-behind deleted) compile option: embeded resource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

 <x:String x:Key="test">
        test string
    </x:String>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

ContentPage1.xaml

```
   <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionary1.xaml"/>
  </ContentPage.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test with the steps provided in the link , everything works fine .

Check the steps below

1. Add a `ContentView` file and rename it ResourceDictionary1 .

   [image]
2. Delete code-behind

   [image]
3. Remove `x:Class="FormsApp.ResourceDictionary1"` in the xaml and change the tag from `ContentView` to `ResourceDictionary` .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" >
    
    
    <x:String x:Key="test">
        test string
    </x:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

4. Usage in other xaml

```
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionary1.xaml"/>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    
    
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="{StaticResource test}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

[image]

---

If you have done all the steps above and problem persists , it must be something wrong with the  file path .

The `ResourceDictionary` file should locate at the same level with the page which using the ResourceDictionary.

- We can place them at the root of the forms project.

  [image]
- We can place them in same folder .

  [image]
- If they are not in same level , we should set the relative file path in the page .

  [image]

```
   // in page4.xaml
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="MyFolder/ResourceDictionary1.xaml"/>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it was not in the same file path and I was trying to put an absolute path instead of the relative one.